# Accessing bean value through c if

Tags: jsp, jstl, struts

I'm stumped. I have a property set in my bean, that I can access through a form on my jsp:

```
<p> <b class="textBold">Is Locked </span>:</b> 
    <html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.isLocked" />
</p>
```

but when I try to access though a hidden property or EL, can't - it shows as blank using this:

```
<html:hidden property="isLocked" value='${user.isLocked}' />

<c:if test='${isLocked}'>
        <p>false:: '${user.isLocked}'</p>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!isLocked}">
        <p>true :: '${user.isLocked}' </p>
</c:if>
```

Where am I going wrong? Can anyone please tell me what I need to fix in my syntax?

Comment: blank is because EL is wrong and returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

use it like

```
<c:if test='${user.locked}'>
```

it will resolve invoke `isLocked()` on user type

Comment: No go. I also created a value, getter and setter in the form as well, but nothing. 

Does it have something to do with a scope/session? I've even tried a <c:out. .> and nothing either.

Answer (score 1):

The EL layer automagically adds getter/setter prefixes for you. For non-boolean properties, EL adds `get/set` and capitalizes the next letter. For boolean properties, EL adds `is/set` and capitalizes the next letter. In a nutshell, change `user.isLocked` to `user.locked`.